# Get data from from repeater via Request.Form to another page

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms, repeater, request.form

I have a simple repeater to list textbox.

**try.aspx**

```
<form id="form1" runat="server" action="try_send.aspx" method="get">
    <div>
 <asp:Repeater ID="ClRpt" runat="server">
      <HeaderTemplate>
      </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="Kod" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("KOD") %>'></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="Amount" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Button ID="ButtonClick" CssClass="bt" runat="server" Text="SEPETE EKLE" Width="100%" UseSubmitBehavior="false" />
    </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:Repeater>
    </div>
</form>
```

**try.aspx.cs:**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string Firma = Session["FirmaID"].ToString();
    string Pryt = "01";
    string GRID = "KATALOG";
    Page.Title = GRID + " ÜRÜN LİSTESİ";
    string SQLGrup = "SQL Here";
    SqlCommand rsCl = new SqlCommand(SQLGrup, bag.Bagla());
    SqlDataReader ClOku = rsCl.ExecuteReader();
    ClRpt.DataSource = ClOku;
    ClRpt.DataBind();
    ClOku.Close();
}
```

I want to send textbox value named `Amount` to **try_send.aspx** file

**try_send.aspx:**

```
<body>
    <asp:Label ID="Amount" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
</body>
```

**try_send.aspx.cs:**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    decimal Amnt = Convert.ToDecimal(Request.Form["Amount"]);
    Amount.Text = Amnt.ToString();
}
```

`Amount` is null when I send the form.

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

In `try.aspx`, you just show a bunch of information in your `Repeater`.

You don't have a button to submit the action.

```
<form id="form1" runat="server"> 
  <asp:Repeater ID="ClRpt" runat="server">
     //content
  </asp:Repeater>
  <asp:Button Id="xx" runat="server" OnClick="xx_OnClick"/>
</form>
```

Then, you redirect and pass the amount you want in the event `click`

```
public void xx_Onclick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     //redirect to try_send with the value amount
}
```

Comment: I must use button in repeater. I am using popup and every popup include a button. Is there any other way for this?